# Unable to restart apache2 service by monit

Tags: apache2, monit

My situation of my apache2 service now :

- main process was down, only child processes were running

How can I get value of main process when it dead or active ?

Comment: The question is a little unclear. Do you want a PID value or a status?

Comment: @matigo 
I mean if I check by " service apache2 status" the result is was inactive. But if I  use " ps aux | grep "/usr/sbin/apache2" | grep -v grep "  the worker process still were running. My perpose I want to make a script to detect apache2 current status.
I tried " ps aux | grep "/usr/sbin/apache2" | grep -v grep | wc -l " but it didn't help. Any suggestion I am welcome.

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion only.

You should enable the PidFile in the httpd.conf file and use this file in your Monit configuration (check process ... with pidfile ...), to find the right process. If you use a mask (check process ... matching ...) Monit will find one process with a matching name, but this is sometimes not the right one.

A sample configuration is available in the wiki, see https://mmonit.com/wiki/Monit/MonitorApacheStatus